# How to create a range selection from the click to where the mouse is dragged?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, range

I need to create a time range slider selection from click to where the mouse is dragged. We have not found a way to do it. But this page is an example of how it should be.

https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/Range_Selector/ImageOnBackground/jQuery/Light/

We have tried with AngularJS, JQuery, D3 and ReactJS, but we have not found the way, since we do not have as much experience in javascript.

Comment: So... what didn't work? You said you tried all these things, but you don't give what problem you are having with any of them. Post some code with errors you might be getting.

Comment: html5's `draggable` attrib will enable event handling that reports source and target elements.